# Trouble with the operator $(T_nf)(t)=\int_{0}^{t}e^{-n(t-x)}f(x)\,dx$ for $t\in[0,1]$ where $f\in(\mathcal C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ with $f(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, solution-verification

**Problem:** Let $f\in(\mathcal C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ such that $f(0)=0$. Define for $n\in\mathbb N$
$$(T_nf)(t)=\int_{0}^{t}e^{-n(t-x)}f(x)\,dx\quad\text{for }t\in[0,1].$$
$\textbf{a)}$ Show that $\|T_nf\|_\infty\leq\displaystyle\frac{1-e^{-n}}{n}\|f\|_\infty.$

$\textbf{Proof Attempt:}$ We observe that
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}
\vert T_nf(t)\vert=\Bigg\vert\int_{0}^{t}e^{-n(t-x)}f(x)\,dx\Bigg\vert &\leq \int_{0}^{t}\vert e^{-n(t-x)}f(x)\vert\,dx\\
&\leq \|f\|_\infty\int_{0}^{t}e^{-n(t-x)}\,dx\\
&= \frac{1-e^{-nt}}{n}\|f\|_\infty\\
&\leq \frac{1-e^{-n}}{n}\|f\|_\infty.
\end{split}\end{equation*}

$\textbf{b)}$ Show that
$$nT_nf(t)-f(t)=\int_{0}^{t}ne^{-nx}[f(t-x)-f(t)]\,dx+e^{-nt}f(t)$$
for all $t\in[0,1]$ and $n\in\mathbb N.$

$\textbf{Proof Attempt:}$ Since
$$\int_{0}^{t}e^{-nx}f(t-x)\,dx=\int_{0}^{t}e^{-n(t-x)}f(x)\,dx\quad\text{and}\quad \int_{0}^{t}e^{-nx}\,dx=\frac{1-e^{nt}}{n},$$
we see that
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}
&\quad\int_{0}^{t}ne^{-nx}[f(t-x)-f(t)]\,dx+e^{-nt}f(t)\\
&=n\int_{0}^{t}e^{-nx}f(t-x)\,dx-nf(t)\int_{0}^{t}e^{-nx}\,dx+e^{-nt}f(t)\\
&= nT_nf(t)-nf(t)\frac{1-e^{nt}}{n}+e^{-nt}f(t)\\
&= nT_nf(t)-f(t).
\end{split}\end{equation*}

$\textbf{c)}$ Show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}nT_nf=f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.

$\textbf{Proof Attemtp:}$ Here I will use the following Lemma: If $h\in\mathcal B(0,1]$, that is, it is bounded on $(0,1]$, such that $\lim\limits_{t\searrow0}\,h(t)=0$, then for $g_n(t)=e^{-nt}h(t)$ where $t\geq0$, we have that $g_n\to0$ uniformly on $(0,1].$ Using the Lemma we have that $e^{-nt}f(t)\to0$ uniformly on $[0,1]$ since also$f(0)=0$ by hypothesis. It remains to handle the integral.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Since $\frac{n}{e^{nx}}\to0$ uniformly on $[\delta,1]$, there exists some $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac{n}{e^{nx}}\leq\varepsilon$ for all $n>N$ and all $x\in[\delta,1]$ where $1>\delta>0$ is fixed. We also choose $\delta$ such that $\vert f(t-x)-f(t)\vert\leq\varepsilon$ for all $\vert x\vert\leq\delta$ by uniform continuity. Then for all $n>N$ and all $t\in[0,1]$ we have that
\begin{align*}
\Bigg\vert\int_{0}^{t}ne^{-nx}[f(t-x)-f(t)]\,dx\Bigg\vert &\leq \varepsilon\int_{0}^{\delta}ne^{-nx}\,dx+2\|f\|_\infty\int_{\delta}^{1}ne^{-nx}\,dx\\ &\leq\varepsilon(1-e^{-n\delta})+2\|f\|_\infty\varepsilon(1-\delta)\\&\leq\varepsilon+2\|f\|_\infty\varepsilon.
\end{align*}
Therefore, $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{t}ne^{-nx}[f(t-x)-f(t)]\,dx\to0$ uniformly on $[0,1].$

---

$\textbf{My Concern:}$ I think I was not successful at handling the integral in part (c).

$\color{blue}{\textbf{Could anyone please check if my proof for part (c) is correct}}?$

Thank you for your time and appreciate any feedback. Comments on parts (a) and (b) are also welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof in part (c) looks good. Maybe it would be better to add a step where you compute the integral $\int_{0}^{\delta}ne^{-nx}\,dx$ explicitely in order to make the bound more visible.